# remote data & query to OpenVMS RMS files

Tags: database-connection, data-access, openvms, vms, dcl

What options exist to query RMS files in OpenVMS? The context for the query/access would be for BI & reporting. Currently, a very old FOCUS (Infomation Builders, v. 6.9.8) is in use, and that only from within the native OpenVMS command line shell.

My challenge working within the VMS environment is that output is intended for off-platform consumption & analysis in Excel, R, and Business Objects/Crystal Reports, and Splunk/Hunk. On-platform, I'm limited in what I can use by whatever I can compile &/or run from within my own user space, and the CONNX & similar tools all look to require a server process in the VMS environment.

Edit: I have accepted a comprehensive answer which, given organizational constraints, may not be feasible. My likely path will be to write additional data extractions jobs in FOCUS, and incur the latency & maintenance overhead that goes along with that.

Comment: Oracle or Oracle Rdb. Or [Datatrieve](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/spddatatrievealphai64v73.pdf).

Comment: [Attunity Connect](http://www.attunity.com/sites/default/files/product_resource/Attunity-Connect-Data-Sheet.pdf) is an answer from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063623/migrating-rms-to-rdb) that allows access to RMS files from other platforms. Is that more along the lines of what you can't ask for on SO, but want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to the reporting to be on-platform, or off-platform (for example with Excel)?

On-platform, after 30+ years, I still really really like Datatrieve, as mentions in a comment.
This tool was created before SQL became all the rage, so its query language takes a little getting use. It knows show to used just about every RMS option (keys, RFA's for collections, joins, locks and sharing,...)

I'm sure there are multiple commercial tools like Focus you mention, and perhaps the IGH tool Vselect for data extraction, column shuffling, sorting. Some would even recommend OpenVMS native SORT but now you are still in Command Line space.

For a (green screen) windows approach, and command line, perhaps check out the freeware tool DIX: http://www.oooovms.dyndns.org/dix/

Off-platform google for "openVMS odbc" (jdbc). You'll find tools from Connx, Easysoft and "Connect" from the company I work for : Attunity.
Those will allow you to use (windows, linux) tools like DBvizualizer or Excell to get to the OpenVMS sourced data.

Perhaps an interesting hybrid could be Attunity's Connect ( "AIS" ) solution which allows for SQL language RMS file access, but on platform (NAV_UTIL) and off-platform, ("Studio, Nav_util, Oracle db-link, ODBC, JDBC, XML, ... )

For better help, please clearify the query still better. Notably the remark " only from within the native OpenVMS command line shell". What's wrong with that? :-). What alternative access did you envision? fake-gui, DECwindows? Native API? Remote API? ...

Hope this helps some already,
Hein

Comment: I'll take a look at some of those options. My challenge working within the VMS environment is that output is intended for off-platform consumption & analysis in Excel, R, and Business Objects/Crystal Reports, and Splunk/Hunk. On-platform, I'm limited in what I can use by whatever I can compile &/or run from within my own user space, and the CONNX & similar tools all look to require a server process in the VMS environment. I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: Hmmm, the business needs the data or it does not. Surely you are joking about your userspace limitations or opportunities. See point 1. THe business needs it and support it, or you have no business working on it. Similarly, If you need a server process, then you need a server process. No ifs ands or buts. You are 99% likely to need that. Ftp is a server also right? Get the management to approve a proper server, or get them fired for incompetency. fwiw, attunity nav_util can give server side, interactive SQL access. No programming, but limited output formatting. DTR is better. DIX is good.

Comment: It's an end-of-life thing; An ERP implementation has just begun. The small legacy systems team is already stretched thin, even more so with the ERP project, and nothing else will require Alpha servers after this, so purchasing additional capacity isn't an option. The OpenVMS system will still be in dwindling use for the next 2+ years though, while the ERP modules come online.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider writing code in a native language such as C or Java. The company I work for uses Apache, DCL scripts in cgi-bin, and the Userbase 4GL to put an Intranet reporting front-end over an OpenVMS legacy system. As long as you wrap the output in HTML etc Apache will stream it back to a browser which will interpret it accordingly. However, with the impending move to Itanium we're faced with no support for porting Userbase. If anyone knows who holds the source code could they tag a reply onto the end of this. We're looking for a terminal (character mode) reporting solution for Itanium as not all users have PCs. If it weren't for this we'd just slap Crystal over CONNX and call it a day. Many thanks.

Further to my previous answer I'm now evaluating R as a reporting solution, using the RODBC to interrogate the RMS database via CONNX using R's RODBC library.

Comment: Further to this the Userbase 4GL now has a future on the resurgent OpenVMS platform. Having discovered and contacted who has the source code/ownership we now have a (tentative) strategy in place to port the code to Itanium.